# Node.js: Package a Client-side Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mobile, ubuntu

I'm currently trying to find a multi-platform solution to package a HTML5 web application (no server dependencies) to a single executable app using node.js and Linux terminal (Ubuntu).

I've tried wkpdftohtml and phantomjs in order to generate a pdf, but they don't support html5 video or audio tags (although modern pdfs do support these).

Are there any libraries or Linux binaries that can satisfy these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a node.js component that acts as a simple web server then you can package the assets + the web server with [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). Contains node + Chromium.

Comment: You could also try http://appjs.org/, which has a similar concept as `node-webkit`.